# Windows Phone - Location data using cellular network

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps, location, cellular-network

I read in various msdn documents ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431800%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/quickstarts/Developing_with_the_Windows_Phone_GPS_%28Location_Services%29#gettinginput)) that windows phone obtains location data from multiple sources such as GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular. My question is, when I am inside my office/home where cellular network (SIM card network) is available, why location service of windows phone not able to fetch current location? As per documentation, if service uses GPS, Wi-Fi, and cellular, it should be able to find current location as cellular network is available.

I see the same behavior in default Maps application of windows phone. It is not able to find location when I am inside my home.

Answer (score 1):

The location service can only locate you over cellular network or WiFi if there is an available record of the location of the cell towers or WiFi hotspots the phone can see.

It's seems that this is not available for your office/home location.

Comment: From where does this info come? From microsoft servers?

Comment: Chintan Shah, have a look also to http://opencellid.org/ web site. You can find a lot of good information regarding to your question.